# How to write a sql query with oracle 10g for wildcard search to check at least 3 chars at the beginning and wildcard can only appear at the end

Tags: sql, oracle10g

How to write a sql query with oracle 10g for wildcard search to check **at least 3 chars at the beginning and wildcard can only appear at the end.**

Comment: where something like 'abc%'

Comment: Do you need a wilcard character at the end or just to use a wildcard operator? What is your schema? Have you tried something already?

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * 
    from yourtable
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(yourcolumn, '[a-z][A-Z]{3}+')
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for response but I already tried this and it is not filtering. It is simply returning all thee records.

Comment: What do you mean by filtering then?